# How to change java card default key with my own keys?

Tags: javacard, globalplatform

I am trying to change a java card default keys (`40 41... 4F`) to my own key set. I tried to use `JCManager` but the process of Modify Key returns `6A 88` meaning that `reference data not found`.

Next I tried GPShell `put_sc_key` to change but same error returned.

What are proper `P1` and `P2` bytes for changing default keys?

How can I fix this?

### APPENDIX 1:

This is the result of `GET DATA` command executed in GPShell as below:

```
mode_211
enable_trace
establish_context
card_connect
select -AID A000000151000000
Command --> 00A4040008A000000151000000
Wrapped command --> 00A4040008A000000151000000
Response <-- 6F108408A000000151000000A5049F6501FF9000
get_data -identifier E0
Command --> 80CA00E000
Wrapped command --> 80CA00E000
Response <-- E012C00401208080C00402208080C004032080809000
E012C00401208080C00402208080C00403208080
card_disconnect
release_context
```

### APPNDIX 2:

This is  the script by which I have tried to change key using GP pro with `ACR83`  reader:

```
gp -lock 010B0371D78377B801F2D62AFC671D95
Warning: no keys given, using default test key 404142434445464748494A4B4C4D4E4F
Failed to communicate with card in JnaCardTerminal{scardHandle=SCardContext{cd00000100000001}, name=ACS ACR83U 0}: SCardTransmit got response 0x57 (null: null)
```

Comment: Try [GlobalPlatformPro](https://github.com/martinpaljak/GlobalPlatformPro). What key version is in the "Key Information Template" (retrievable via `GET DATA` as tag 0xE0)...

Comment: @vlp Unfortunately, my reader is not compatible with GlobalPlatformPro. I have added APPENDIX 1 to show `GET DATA` execution details. It seem "Key Information Template" is "DES – mode (EBC/CBC) implicitly known" according to GlobalPlatform.

Comment: What reader are you using? GlobalPlatformPro can work with virtually any smart card reader (there are buggy ones, but that's a different story)

Comment: @MartinPaljak Thank you Martin for your response. I'm using an **ACR83** (https://www.acs.com.hk/en/products/34/acr83-pineasy-smart-card-reader/), and GPShell not GP pro. I will try GP pro and inform you from the result. (I think, I am using wrong parameters in GPShell for `put_sc_key` command, and I need help for proper Global Platform APDUs).

Comment: That reader has PC/SC CCID compatible interface. It *should* be a breeze to get it to work with GlobalPlatform. If something is going wrong, it might not be the reader or reader interface, is what I'm saying.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes I can use this reader with GPShell. Now, my question is "is there a sample APDU command by which I can replace default keys on javacard?". I think I am doing something wrong with `put_sc_key` command in GPShell to replace default keys cause it returns `reference data not found`, so is JCManager.

Comment: You might be trying to replace a key that is stored in ROM. Generally you simply have to put a new key in one of the lower ID positions... I was trying to answer, but I won't without being able to quote the standard...

Comment: @MartinPaljak I tried to change default key using GP pro and results are mentioned in APPENDIX 2. I have installed ACR83U latest driver and I am using windows 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found [pyResMan](https://javacardos.com/tools/pyresman) useful in my case. It is a python application which helps you easily list your key sets on your cards and add/modify keys.